# RuntimeException: unable to instantiate application - Class not found?

Tags: android, runtimeexception

I've been developing an app for some time now and have been deploying it straight to my device for testing. However, as the development is coming to a close, I've made the first version available on the google play store.

However, after downloading the app from the play store, it crashes immediately on startup. Fortunately android allows the end user to examine the stack trace, which appears as:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.jysoftware.jyapp.CustomApp: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.jysoftware.jyapp.CustomApp"
on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.jysoftware.jyapp-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.jysoftware.jyapp-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]] .......
```

The `ClassNotFound` is the same class as referenced in my manifest as:

```
<application
    android:name="com.jysoftware.jyapp.CustomApp"
    ....
</application>
```

Any ideas what could be causing this, or where I should start to look? I'm at a loss as to why this should work when it is directly deployed from eclipse but does not work when downloaded from the play store.

Comment: Perhaps ProGuard renamed it.

Comment: Cheers but I don't use ProGuard (yet!)

Comment: What are your dependencies (if any)?

Comment: Have you tested the signed apk before uploading it?

Comment: Usually, making a release version of your app goes through ProGuard automatically.